# Converting miles above ground to zoom level?

Tags: scale, zoom

I've got a spec that details what features are to appear on a map at certain number of miles above the earth.  So for example "Render this point when closer than 400 miles above the earth".

How do I convert that to a scale? I'm using a standard zxy base map so I need to change the spec to "render this point when zoom level greater than 6"

Is there a standard calculation for this?

Comment: Most mapping software uses *scale*, which is a *rough approximation*, due to pixel size in the physical monitor. Height above Earth is even more approximate, since it depend on distance form the monitor.

Comment: You want to convert "miles above the earth" to something like "1:25,000 scale"? And what do you mean by "standard zoom level"?

Comment: @Spacedman edited to try and make myself clearer. by standard zoom level I mean the 1-20 levels that google use.

Answer (score 3):

I don't know if there is a standard formula for calculating zoom level based on altitude but you can do some trigonometric calculations.

I assume your field of view is nadir which means `FOV(angle) = 45 degrees`

Altitude in your case, `A = 400 miles = 643738 meters`

and now i will assume your map extent is `1000 x 1000 pixels` so number of pixels from the center of map, `n = 500 px`

If `R` is the resolution in `meter/pixel` then we have the following relation:

```
tan FOV = n x R/A
R = A/n x tan FOV
```

With `FOV = 45`, `A = 643738` and `n = 500` we get `R = 1287.5 m/px`

[image]

In this case your approximate map scale is `1:4,000,000` and `zoom level = 7`

Depends on your map extent, you can cross check resolution value in the above table and get your approximate map scale and zoom_level.

Hope this will solve your problem.

Comment: Thanks, it's a great answer, better than my question deserves.  But I'm confused why the size of the map is important.  If I were on google maps in earth mode then the image at zoom level X is what I would see in my eye if I was hovering at Y meters above the earth regardless of screen size.